# Gradient overlay on Image with single line of CSS

Tags: css, css-gradients

I'm trying to put a gradient on a background image using this code

```
background: url('../img/newspaper.jpeg'),linear-gradient(to bottom right,#002f4b, #dc4225);
background-size: cover;
```

I'm getting the image but the gradient is not being applied

Answer (score 5):

Add the gradient first and then add the image url, just like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.95),
                            rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75),
                            rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.75),
                            rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.95)),
                            url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
```

Or look at the snippet below:

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(
    rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.45),
    rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.25),
    rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.25),
    rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.45)),
    url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0,47,75,.9), rgba(220,66,37,.9)), url(http://placehold.it/350x350);
  background-size: cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**do it in one line like below, I gave an example for that, see it**

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to start-direction end-direction, color1, color2, url("imageUrl");
```

```css
#hero {
  height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(99, 102, 241, .9), rgba(219, 99, 139, .9)), url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/305/600/300.webp?hmac=QcFzy6dHM3Qs5MQwTjvnHEkSoTGAfg_VRgbH5g7pUQM");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>
```